# Attributes in Linked Entities in FetchXML Kingswaysoft SSIS returning NULL

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, kingswaysoft

I am trying to migrate quote details using the Kingswaysoft SSIS CRM migration package from CRM2016 on premise to D365.

To read the data I am using Fetch XML, on the quotedetails entity and want to link to the quote entity to retreive quotenumber and revisionnumber.

My current query looks like the following -

```
<fetch mapping='logical'>
  <entity name="quotedetail">
    <attribute name="baseamount" />
    <link-entity name="quote" from="quoteid" to="quoteid" link-type="inner" alias="quote">
      <attribute name="quotenumber" />
      <attribute name="revisionnumber" />
      <filter>
        <condition attribute='revisionnumber' operator='eq' value='1'/>
       </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Using the data viewer shows that all values in the linked entity are returned as null, and therefore I cannot use these as a lookup for the quoteid.

[Data Viewer Results Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21E4t.png)

Using this FetchXML statement in XRMtoolbox however does show the fields correctly.

Comment: if the same fetchxml returns you the correct data inside XrmToolBox, then you should contact KingswaySoft support

Comment: make sue that there is no field security applied to that field or the user that you are using for migration has full read privileges

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with versions 21.2 and 22.1

Answer (score 0):

According to KingswaySoft official "Known Limitation", this is a known issue with a workaround:

> In the CDS/CRM Source Component, with the FetchXML option, if you are using linked entities in your FetchXML queries, the CRM component returns NULL values for the fields from linked entities. **To avoid this, provide an alias for each linked entity.**

I.e. you should provide an alias in the FetchXML to avoid this issue. I got it working in my case by providing the alias on the attribute, meaning you would have to do the following:

```xml
<fetch mapping='logical'>
  <entity name="quotedetail">
    <attribute name="baseamount" />
    <link-entity name="quote" from="quoteid" to="quoteid" link-type="inner">
      <attribute name="quotenumber" alias="quote_quotenumber"/>
      <attribute name="revisionnumber" alias="quote_revisionnumber" />
      <filter>
        <condition attribute='revisionnumber' operator='eq' value='1'/>
       </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Reference: https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-365/help-manual/crm/Known-Limitations